# Backpropagation algorithm with multiple learning constants

Tags: javascript, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm currently writing a paper on how to build a simple neural network made of an input, an hidden layer and an output. While writing the part on the backpropagation, I was thinking of an easier algorithm to explain how backpropagation works (the paper is intended for non-specialist). So I read this paper : https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-10-neural-networks/

And I find this formula to update weights :

```
NEW WEIGHT = WEIGHT + ERROR * INPUT * LEARNING CONSTANT
```

I decided to give it a try by updating "input-to-hidden" and "hidden-to-output" weights with the same learning constant. It quickly fails. Then, I decided to apply a different learning constant for the input layer's weights and the hidden layer's weights.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Input.length; i++) {
  for (var a = 0; a < HiddenWeights.length; a++) { // learning constant one
    HiddenWeights[a] = HiddenWeights[a] + TargetCalculated * Input[i] * 0.01 
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < Input.length; i++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < InputWeights.length; b++) { // learning constant two
    InputWeights[b] = InputWeights[b] + TargetCalculated * Input[i] * 0.001 
  }
}
```

With this method to update the weights with separate learning constants my neural network seems to be able to properly backpropagate. My question is : how can I explain this?

Thank you,

Comment: What is target calculated?

Comment: Hi ! Sorry, my code is unclear : TargetCalculated is the difference between the target and the calculated value

Comment: Where are you getting the target value?

Comment: I didn't post the full code. The target value is just the Output.

Comment: What was your learning constant before?or do you mean now you're trying two learning constants instead of one?

Comment: To keep it simple in my paper, I didn't use bias or learning constant before the backpropagation. When I try to find a method to update weights, I use 0.01 for "input-to-hidden" and "hidden-to-output". Using a "true" backpropagation method, I notice that the change in "hidden-to-output" is more important than the change for "intput-to-hidden", so I decided to apply to different learning constant

Comment: So to clarify, your question is really why is a learning constant important?

Comment: No. I know how to explain that. I need to explain why this method could work, and why we need different learning constant.

Comment: the formula works because you're calculating the direction you need to direct your weights and heading slowly in that direction, look up gradient descent.  I'm not sure why the two different learning constants are needed. Could just be coincidence.

Comment: Thank you @palebone ! I will do further reasearch before publishing my paper